# scan Excel column based on another column value

Tags: excel

I want to check one entire column with value in another column and then assign a value in another column value to matching row cell.
Eg-

```
A   B   C   D
1   10  X   
2   3   Y   
3   2   Z   
4   11  K
```

What I want to do is take one value at a time from column A eg 1 and then scan through Column B if matches the Column A (value 1) then assign x to that row under D. eg if we check A3 ( value 2) with column B and found 2  is on B4 then D4 = Z. Like this I want to check all values in column in A against column B assign relevant vale from column C to Column D

How can I do this, can someone please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a straightforward `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX-MATCH`

Comment: Thanks this works , appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
= IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH(A3,$B$2:$B$5,0)),"no match")
```

See below.

[image]

Comment: @nipunaweerasinghe It does work... please see my post again. I edited to show result. It searches for value `A3` (2) in `B` column, and returns the corresponding value in the `C` column. How doesn't it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$C$5,2,0),"")
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome, please don't forget mark my answer as the answer in your post I am building my reputation :)